# How to crawl each page code attached in C#?

Tags: c#, html, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying crawl an website from http://stock.hankyung.com/news/app/newslist.php?cid=01.

My coding is supposed to crawl all the information that each title gives just for the first page. Now I want to crawl where after finishing the first page I want to crawl the next page and following 1->2->3->.

[image]

Comment: Read why an [image of source code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the page number in the link.

```
    int page_number;
    string url_link = "http://stock.hankyung.com/news/app/newslist.php?cid=01&page=";
    for (int i = 1; i <= page_numnber; i++) {
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url_link + i);
      // Code here
    }
```

I hope it helps

Edit : 
 When you inspect the last page button below

```
<a href="http://stock.hankyung.com/news/app/newslist.php?cid=01&page=43940" class="btn last">
```

You could select the Element with

```
   IWebElement lastPageElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='btn last']"));
```

Then select the `href` properties.

```
string page_number_string = lastPageElement.GetAttribute("href");
```

Then get a Substring out of it

```
page_number_string = page_number_string .Substring(60);
```

Cast the `string` to an `int`

```
int page_number= Int32.Parse(page_number_string);
```

At the end it would be like that:

```
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stock.hankyung.com/news/app/newslist.php?cid=01");
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
  IWebElement lastPageElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='btn last']"));
  string page_number_string = lastPageElement.GetAttribute("href");
  page_number_string = page_number_string .Substring(60);
  int page_number Int32.Parse(page_number_string);
  string url_link = "http://stock.hankyung.com/news/app/newslist.php?cid=01&page=";
     for (int i = 1; i <= page_number; i++) {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url_link + i);
        // Code here
     }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but when I run the code it says "Use of unassigned local variable 'page_number'. is this mean I need to set page_number as maximum number the website has so far?

Comment: See Edit in my post :)

Answer (score 0):

from the link use query string attribute `page`  to access each page for example 
to reach page No. 4 the link will be like this

`http://stock.hankyung.com/news/app/newslist.php?cid=01&page=4`

you can use loop to reach all pages